# Como multiplicar o valor de 3 inputs usando javascript puro?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer a multiplicação de 3 campos, o valor total será retornado em um novo label. Porém não estou conseguindo. Quando fiz com 1 campo apenas, funcionou:

http://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/PLrCK/

Até tentei fazer um `if (isNaN(` porém não adiantou. Não apresenta erro, porém não funciona!

Comment: O teu problema é que ao fazeres onchange de um elemento estás a passar uma string e não um conteudo

Comment: creio que tera de fazer o onchange somente no ultimo para ter todos os 3 parametros se não nao vai ter jeito

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altere a sua variável total:

```
 var Total = document.getElementById(comprimentoID).value * document.getElementById(LarguraID).value * document.getElementById(InclinacaoID).value;
```

O problema é que você está passando para a função o ID do campo que contém o valor que precisa ser multiplicado.

Altere também o evento onChange de cada campo, no lugar de passar o valor preenchido no campo comprimento, passa o ID do campo:

```
<input id="txt_Comprimento_1"  type="number"   onchange="MudaPreco('txt_Comprimento_1','txt_Largura_1','txt_Inclinicacao_1','PrecoProd_1')" /><br>
<input id="txt_Largura_1" type="number" onchange="MudaPreco('txt_Comprimento_1','txt_Largura_1','txt_Inclinicacao_1','PrecoProd_1')"   /><Br>
<input id="txt_Inclinicacao_1" type="number" onchange="MudaPreco('txt_Comprimento_1','txt_Largura_1','txt_Inclinicacao_1','PrecoProd_1')"  /><br><br>
```

Comment: Assim só funciona para o primeiro `onchange`

Comment: @CesarMiguel funciona para todos. O valor só vai ser calculado após preencher os 3 campos, caso contrário ocorre uma multiplicação por 0.

Comment: Funciona se alterares o comprimentoID que tens ai

Comment: @CesarMiguel entendi, vou alterar.

Answer (score 4):

O teu problema é que ao fazeres o `onchange` estás sempre a passar duas string's, logo vais multiplicar o valor da input que estás a passar (correctamente) mais duas strings.

O teu erro estava:

```
onchange="MudaPreco(this.value,'txt_Largura_1','txt_Inclinicacao_1','PrecoProd_1')
```

E o que a função ia receber era:

```
function MudaPreco(4, txt_Largura_1, txt_Inclinicacao_1, PrecoProd_1)
```

Assim ao fazeres o calculo da `var Total` ficava:

```
var Total = 4* txt_Largura_1* txt_Inclinicacao_1
```

Eis o que te aconselho a fazer:

```
    comprimentoID = $('#txt_Comprimento_1').val();
    LarguraID = $('#txt_Largura_1').val();
    InclinacaoID = $('#txt_Inclinicacao_1').val();

    var Total = comprimentoID * LarguraID * InclinacaoID;
```

Deixo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/PLrCK/1/) com um exemplo de resolução.

**EDIT: Sem JQuery**

Podes usar o `document.getElementById('txt_Comprimento_1').value` que é nativo do javascript.

[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/PLrCK/6/) sem jquery.

Comment: Certo, vou editar

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, realmente funciona, porém por outros motivos estou a implementar em javascript puro, porém caso não consiga vou utilizar sua solução.

Comment: `document.getElementById` é javascript puro. Estás a vontade :)

Comment: agora vi que esta 100%, valeu